# error: not found: value jsDependencies value / is not a member of sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, sbt-plugin

I'm upgrading sbt-scalajs version from 0.6.x to 1.0.0.

This is my old `plugins.sbt` config

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.33")
addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-scalajs-crossproject" % "0.6.0")
```

My new plugins.sbt is

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-scalajs-crossproject" % "1.0.0")
```

Below is my old build.sbt

```
 import sbtcrossproject.CrossPlugin.autoImport.{crossProject, CrossType}
 
name := "sjs-test-error"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.12.10",
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.12.10"),
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-deprecation", "-Xlint",  "-Ypartial-unification"),
  Compile / compile / scalacOptions  += "-Ywarn-unused-import",
  Compile / doc / scalacOptions += "-no-link-warnings"
)

val core = crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform)
  .in(file("core"))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(
    name := "sjs-test-error",
  )
  .jsSettings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.1"
    ),
    jsDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.webjars.npm" % "viz.js" % "1.7.0" / "1.7.0/viz.js"
    )
  )

lazy val coreJVM = core.jvm
lazy val coreJS = core.js

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .aggregate(coreJVM, coreJS)
  .settings(commonSettings)
```

My new build.sbt is same except the `import sbtcrossproject.CrossPlugin.autoImport.{crossProject, CrossType}` is commented.

When I run `sbt clean compile` I get below error -

> /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/OS/reftree/build.sbt:28: error: not found: value jsDependencies
>
> jsDependencies ++= Seq(
> ^
>
> /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/OS/reftree/build.sbt:31: error: value / is not a member of sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID
>
> ```
>  "org.webjars.npm" % "viz.js" % "1.7.0" / "1.7.0/viz.js"
> ```

This is working fine in 0.6.x sbt-scalajs plugin. I don't know how to write the same for 1.0.0 version

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [the release notes of Scala.js 1.0.0](https://www.scala-js.org/news/2020/02/25/announcing-scalajs-1.0.0/):

> If you use `jsDependencies` (or rely on the `jsDependencies` of your transitive dependencies):
>
> - Add `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-jsdependencies" % "1.0.0")` in `project/plugins.sbt`
> - Add `.enablePlugins(JSDependenciesPlugin)` to Scala.js projects
> - Add `.jsConfigure(_.enablePlugins(JSDependenciesPlugin))` to `crossProject`s